# PostgreSQL index on string range

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have three queries:

(1) `select date, id, name, year, price from table where year <= '2010'`

(2) `select date, id, name, year, price from table where year between '2011' and '2015'`

(3) `select date, id, name, year, price from table where year >= '2016'`

I want them to be faster, so I created index (1) `create index idx_1 on table(year)` and (2) `create index idx_2 on table(year desc)`. I also tried `create index idx on table(year) where year <= '2010'`, but the query plan is still seq scan, how should I create index?

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers as strings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sadly I am not able to change the column types..

Comment: And just found that there can be 'NA' value in column "year".. so it must be string..

Comment: If you want to store "not available", use a `NULL` value in an `integer` column. **Never**, ever store numbers as strings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reminder, I wish I could change it but I have no rights to do it..

Comment: None of those queries look very selective.  Using an index would probably be slower, unless 2011 is the first year for which you have data or 2015 the last.  This would still be true even if you used a sane data type.

Comment: When you use TEXT as datatype, you should use the string operators only. That means you can't use operators like BETWEEN, < and >. That sucks, but that's the way it is when you're not using a proper datatype. And when values like NA are a valid year, your problem gets only worse...

Comment: Thanks for all of your comment.. So I think I need to ask helps from the guys who manage the db.. to see if they can change the type.. many thanks for all of you :)